# Angular update Local Storage value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I was looking at some examples of angular with local storage as i inherited a project that is using it.

This is what I am seeing

```
var order;
order = userCache.get('order');
console.log('order from cache', order);
```

Chrome dev tools json output

```
{
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "serviceLocation": {
        "verified": true,
        "formattedAddress": "2110 El Pinto Rd, Sullivan City, TX 78595",
        "address1": "2110 El Pinto Rd",
        "city": "Sullivan City",
        "state": "TX",
        "zip": "78595"
      },
      "additionalLocations": [],
      "services": {
        "electric": {
          "selectedProgramId": null,
          "utilityAndProgram": null,
          "serviceProvider": null
        },
        "naturalGas": {
          "selectedProgramId": null,
          "utilityAndProgram": null,
          "serviceProvider": null
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "authorizedParty": {
    "firstName": "sdfsad",
    "lastName": "asdgfdsaf",
    "phone": "(222) 222-2222"
  },
  "contactPreference": "phone",
  "signature": null,
  "isNew": false
}
```

What I want to do is just UPDATE the `address` field by adding in some more data.

So first I was just trying to read some of that data

Since i put in javascript a object called `order`  , based on the json object structure,  shouldn't I be able to just do ?

```
**UPDATE**
```

Ok, i figured this part out..  array  [0]

```
var orderAddress = order.lineItems[0].serviceLocation.address1;
console.log(orderAddress);
```

And then How can I update that value ?  `setItem`  or `set`  ?

Update on userCache  it looks like this

```
.service('userCache', function (CacheFactory) {
// NOTE : Used to store specific information about this user, gets cleared on logout.
return CacheFactory.createCache('userCache', {
  maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // Items added to this cache expire after 30 days.
  deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive',
  storageMode: 'localStorage'
});
```

});

Comment: what is userCache - is it a library or simply a library that is referencing LocalStorage?

Comment: you'll need to save the object with your edited data - and then set your localstorage, (I assume `userCache.set('order')`)

Comment: I'm guessing `userCache.set('order', order);`, after you've changed the `object`.

Comment: @DenisTsoi   it is LocalStorage  , I posted an update to the code  thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have to update data in your local storage, you usually need to:

1. Parse data from local storage
2. Update the entry you want to be updated
3. Save data in local storage

This is due to the **string** nature of local storage: when you save objects, arrays or whatever you want, the are converted to string since Local Storage is a **string** storage.

But since you're a lucky boy and you're using Angular, there's plenty of modules you can use to manage local storage without the need to worry about stringification.

My personal favourite is [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

--- **EDIT** ---

Well, with `angular-cache` you simply follow the steps above:

1. `var data = JSON.parse(userCache.get('order'))`
2. `data.lineItems[0].serviceLocation.address = *whatever*`
3. `userCache.put('order', data)`

Comment: With my specific code ,  code you explain with code?

Comment: Since local storage does not have "exipration date", you're probably dealing with cookies, not with local storage. However, we need to know what CacheFactory looks like to help you out

Comment: Well I didn't know that module, but you can take a look at the edit. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

First Get the value from Local Storage
Updte It and agian set the updated JSON with the key
It will update.

In Pure javascript , It will be like.

`var storage = {};

storage.setUpdateData = function(updatedJson) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("keyName",updatedJson);
}`

Comment: Missed the Angular Specific Syntax, Its pure javascript.